# Why does the second yield return first in this generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, yield

In the code below, why does the *first* call to `next()` return the value that comes after the *second* `yield` keyword?

```
function* generatorFunction() {
  yield (yield 'the second yield')();
}

function func(x) {
  return 'func passed to the second next()';
}

var iterator = generatorFunction();

var firstValue = iterator.next().value;
var secondValue = iterator.next(func).value;

console.log(firstValue); // "the second yield"
console.log(secondValue); // "func passed to the second next()"
```

On the first `next()` it treats the rest of the line after the first `yield` as an expression, right? Does that mean `(yield x)()` evaluates to x, but doesn't actually pause on the yield while it's evaluating it?

Then the second call to `next` passes in a function, does that function take the place of `(yield 'the second yield')` and so get executed and then return its value.

Can anyone help explain what's going on here?

BTW this serves no practical purpose, I'm just going through the [es6katas](http://tddbin.com/#?kata=es6/language/generator/send-function).

Comment: Agree with @estus just adding: what would the first `yield` return if it were to return first?

Comment: I guess I was taking too literally 'stops on the first yield'. (I was baffled as to what it would actually return.) So it yields in the order that the yield expressions are evaluated, just like `returns`. Makes perfect sense, thanks guys. @estus feel free to copy that to an answer.

Comment: Sure. I've augmented it with operator precedence explanation instead of appealing to 'language sense'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example but pretty much self-explaining.

The expression

```
yield (yield 'the second yield')();
```

is evaluated inside out, according to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table).

First of all, right part of outer `yield` is evaluated, `(yield 'the second yield')()`.

Left function part, `(yield 'the second yield')` group is evaluated first. `'the second yield'` value is returned from first `next()` call, the generator is paused on inner `yield`.

The generator resumes on `next(func)` call, `yield 'the second yield'` is evaluated to sent value (`func`), then right function part `func()` is evaluated to `'func passed to the second next()'`.

Finally, left part of outer `yield` is evaluated, `'func passed to the second next()'` is returned from second `next(func)` call, the generator is paused.